Homogenous but not isotropic manifolds
$(M,g)$ is homogeneous if  $\forall a,b\in M$ there is an isometry $f:M\to M$ such that $f(a)=b$
$(M, g)$ is called isotropic if $\forall p\in M$ $x,y\in T_pM$ of unit length, there is an isometry $f:M\to M$ s.t. $f_\ast(x)=y$
I know that Every connected isotropic manifold is homogeneous (given 2 points, take the middle of the geodesics connecting them)
Now, are there homogenous manifolds that are not isotropic? Please, explain in detail if so.

A cylinder $S^1\times \mathbb{R}$ will do the job !
In general, isometries of a product Riemannian manifolds are not the "product of isometries of the factors", but in this simple case I hope we can agree it's true: an isometry of the cylinder is of the type $$(x,y)\mapsto (r(x),\pm y+a),$$ where $r\in O(2)$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$. If you want a rigorous proof of this fact, check this answer. Clearly the isometries of the cylinder map tangent vectors like $(v,0)$ in tangent vectors of the same kind (the last coordinate stays equal to $0$), so the cylinder is not isotropic, but it's homogeneous.
I want to add an interesting curiosity. Isotropic connected riemannian manifolds are completely classified up to isometry and are:

Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{E}^n$,
Spheres $\mathbb{S}^n$,
Hyperbolic (real) spaces $\mathbb{H}^n$,
Hyperbolic complex spaces $\mathbb{H}^n\mathbb{C}$,
Hyperbolic quaternionic spaces $\mathbb{H}^n\mathbb{H}$,
Hyperbolic octonionic plane $\mathbb{H}^2\mathbb{O}$,
Projective real spaces $\mathbb{P}^n\mathbb{R}$,
Projective complex spaces $\mathbb{P}^n\mathbb{C}$,
Projective quaternionic spaces $\mathbb{P}^n\mathbb{H}$,
Projective octonionic plane $\mathbb{P}^2\mathbb{O}$.

While homogeneous Riemannian manifolds are much more! They are precisely the manifolds $G/H$ where $G$ is a Lie group and $H\leq G$ is a compact subgroup (basically a complete classification is near impossible).

Great! Thank you very much

The last sentence is wrong, it should be "...quotient manifolds $G/H$ where $G$ is a Lie group and $H\le G$ is a compact subgroup..."

@MoisheKohan Thank you for the correction!

Still wrong: $G/H$ is not a group, just a manifold.

@MoisheKohan Thank you again!

It is all good now!
